# Is it possible to create a custom app for Microsoft Teams that dosn't use a central service provider?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am working on adding support for our cloud storage solution to MS Teams but there is no central server you can send http messages to and get meaningful relies back from. I have no experience with creating Teams apps so I was hoping someone with Teams apps experience could tell me if this is even possible. At this point I only need my app to work on Windows and OS X.

This is how I would like my Teams App to work:

Each member of the team already has our cloud storage app running locally on their machine which provides access to the files.

Within MS Teams the user adds a file reference to a message via a message extension that would result in a link unfurl creating a card that contains an 'Open' button. The URL in the card would be one generated by our locally running cloud storage app. Other members of the team could then open this file by clicking the 'Open' button. The action of the open button would be to send the URL to our cloud storage app that would then open the local copy of the file on that team members machine.

Is it possible to do something like this within a Teams app? The communication between the Teams app and our cloud storage app would be done over our own protocol.

If it weren't for the fact that all bot communication must be done over https rather than http the local cloud storage app could act as the server.

Answer (score 0):

All the communication in Teams with 3P apps needs to happen over https public endpoint. You could use [ngrok](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tutorials/get-started-dotnet-app-studio#host-the-sample-app) to tunnel to local.